# How to populate references in a Firestore query return?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find the best way to handle nested references in a query return.

In my data model I have contentTexts, and dailyPublications.

The dailyPublications has two properties that are nested arrays of 12 contentText references.

In my Ionic 6 application I'm trying to query the data.

```
todaysContent = [];

async getTodaysContent(): Promise<any[]> {
    const todaysDate = new Date();
    const dailyPublicationsRef = query(collectionGroup(firestore, 'dailypublications'), where('date', '==', new Date(todaysDate.getFullYear(), todaysDate.getMonth(), todaysDate.getDate())));
    const docSnap = await getDocs(dailyPublicationsRef);
    docSnap.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data());
    });

    console.log(docSnap);

    return this.todaysContent;
    
  }
```

This returns the object with the properties, "mensContent" and "womensContent".

But should I go through each reference and query it? That would be 25 reads per pageview.

Whats the best way to populate the references with as minimal reads as necessary?

Comment: "12 contentText references" Can you clarify what that means? Are those `DocumentReference` fields?

Answer (score 0):

If your `contentText` fields are `DocumentReference` values, then you indeed will need to call `get()` on each of them separate to load their value.

Firestore does not have any built-in server-side join mechanism to do this for you. But even if it did: that would require it to read each of those documents, so you'd still be charged for the document reads.

---

The common solution for this is to modify your data model for the use-case. If you need to get the text for those 12 documents and don't want to perform a separate read for each, consider putting the text of each document directly into the `dailypublications` document.

This sort of data duplication is *very* common in NoSQL data modeling, and is a large part of the reason why they scale to such massive numbers of reads.

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading up since I'm coming from a LAMP background and pretty new to TS and NoSQL.

I'm reading CloudFunctions help organize data. Should I look into that as a way to organize this data?

Comment: If you're new to NoSQL, I'd recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).